# Scan a linked list in c

Tags: c, list, scanf

I've been asked to create a linked list in c. The user should insert the list by adding one digit at a time from the most significant digit to the less significant one. The problem is that when I print the list (not in reverse), after having it scanned (e.g. calling the function with 3 numdigits), it prints it backwards (tail to head and not head to tail). I am typing 3, 2, 1 and it prints 321 instead of 123. I'm really stuck here. Any help?

```
typedef struct node{ 
int digit;
struct node *next;
}listnode_t;


listnode_t *create_list(int numdigits) 
{
listnode_t *ptr, *head;
ptr = (listnode_t*)malloc(sizeof(listnode_t));
ptr -> next= NULL;
head = ptr;

int i=0;
int userdigit;

do{
    scanf("%d",&userdigit);
    if (userdigit<0 || userdigit>9)
    {
        printf("Give from 0 to 9\n");
    }
    else{
        ptr -> digit = userdigit;
        ptr -> next = (listnode_t*)malloc(sizeof(listnode_t));
        ptr = ptr -> next;

        i+=1;
    }
}while (i<numdigits);

ptr -> next = NULL;

return head;

}   

void print_number(listnode_t *head)
{
if ((head->next) == NULL){

    printf("Empty list\n");
    return;
}

while ((head->next)!= NULL){
    printf("%d", (head->digit));
    head = head -> next;
}

return ;
}
```

Comment: Please delete you picture and add your codes as plain text.

Comment: So what you expect is, that the list is printed in reverse? Or is it the insertion of your elements that are wrong?

Comment: Reading about linked lists, I get that when you insert a number by scaning, e.g. the number 321, normally I should type 1-2-3, so that the digit 3 goes to the tail of the list and the digit 1 is the head. While in my code, the opposite happens. The digit 3 as I understand it, is the head node of the list.

Comment: You have to clean up and refactor your code. It's a mess.

Comment: hint: change next to previous, head to tail, and the code to follow suit.

Comment: This is what I have problem to understand. This change. Previous or next is just the 'member' of the struct node. What if I change it?

Comment: You are inserting new elements at the tail of the list. That means the last element you insert, will be last in the list. If you insert your elements at the head instead, you will get the order you have expected. However, in that case you will have an updated head pointer after each iteration. But instead, you will not touch the other elements at all (not updating any pointers to next et c.)

Answer (score 1):

Well that's exactly what printing a linked list does; printing the list from the head to the tail, e.g if your input is 1,2,3 then :

- head->digit == 1
- head->next->digit == 2
- head->next->next->digit == 3

Still though if you want to reverse the linked list you can do that using a function, as an example :

```
node* reverse(node* head)
{
    node* prev    = NULL;
    node* current = head;
    node* next;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        next  = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    head = prev;
    return head;
}
```

More info here : https://www.zentut.com/c-tutorial/c-linked-list/#Reverse_linked_list